# Visitor/Listener code for a while loop in ANTLR 4

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

So far i have searched the whole "The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference" book as well as many sites for an answer to my question  and i still can't find anything on the topic.

I am using ANTLR 4 to create a sub-set of the C language that does some basic functionality. What i have no idea about is how to implement a simple while loop in my Visitor class. So far i got this in my grammar:

```
grammar Expr;

prog:   stat+ ;

stat:   expr NEWLINE                # printExpr
    |   ID '=' expr NEWLINE         # assign
    |   loop NEWLINE                # whileLoop
    |   relational NEWLINE          # relat
    |   NEWLINE                     # blank 
    ;

expr:   expr op=('*'|'/') expr      # MulDiv
    |   expr op=('+'|'-') expr      # AddSub
    |   INT                         # int
    |   ID                          # id
    |   '(' expr ')'                # parens
    ;

relational:     expr op=(GREATER|LESS) expr     # GreaterEqual
          ;

loop:   'while' '('relational')' NEWLINE? '{'stat*'}'   #while
    ;

GREATER : '>' ;
LESS : '<' ;
MUL :   '*' ; // assigns token name to '*' used above in grammar
DIV :   '/' ;
ADD :   '+' ;
SUB :   '-' ;
ID  :   [a-zA-Z]+ ;      // match identifiers
INT :   [0-9]+ ;         // match integers
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ;     // return newlines to parser (is end-statement signal)
WS  :   [ \t]+ -> skip ; // toss out whitespace
```

This way i could have multiple statements inside a while loop. My Visitor class looks like this:

```
public class EvalVisitor extends ExprBaseVisitor<Integer> {

/** "memory" for our calculator; variable/value pairs go here */
Map<String, Integer> memory;

public EvalVisitor() {
    memory = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
}

/** ID '=' expr NEWLINE */
@Override
public Integer visitAssign(ExprParser.AssignContext ctx) {      
    String id = ctx.ID().getText();  // id is left-hand side of '='
    int value = super.visit(ctx.expr());   // compute value of expression on right        
    memory.put(id, value);           // store it in our memory
    return value;
}

/** expr NEWLINE */
@Override
public Integer visitPrintExpr(ExprParser.PrintExprContext ctx) {
    Integer value = super.visit(ctx.expr()); // evaluate the expr child
    System.out.println(value);         // print the result
    return 0;                          // return dummy value
}

/** INT */
@Override
public Integer visitInt(ExprParser.IntContext ctx) {
    return Integer.valueOf(ctx.INT().getText());
}

/** ID */
@Override
public Integer visitId(ExprParser.IdContext ctx) {
    String id = ctx.ID().getText();
    if ( memory.containsKey(id) ) return memory.get(id);        
    return 0;
}

/** expr op=('*'|'/') expr */
@Override
public Integer visitMulDiv(ExprParser.MulDivContext ctx) {
    int left = super.visit(ctx.expr(0));  // get value of left subexpression
    int right = super.visit(ctx.expr(1)); // get value of right subexpression
    if ( ctx.op.getType() == ExprParser.MUL ) return left * right;
    return left / right; // must be DIV
}

/** expr op=('+'|'-') expr */
@Override
public Integer visitAddSub(ExprParser.AddSubContext ctx) {
    int left = super.visit(ctx.expr(0));  // get value of left subexpression
    int right = super.visit(ctx.expr(1)); // get value of right subexpression        
    if ( ctx.op.getType() == ExprParser.ADD ) return left + right;
    return left - right; // must be SUB

}

/** '(' expr ')' */
@Override
public Integer visitParens(ExprParser.ParensContext ctx) {
    return super.visit(ctx.expr()); // return child expr's value
}

@Override
public boolean visitGreaterEqual(GreaterEqualContext ctx) {
    int left = super.visit(ctx.expr(0));
    int right = super.visit(ctx.expr(1));

    if(ctx.op.getType() == ExprParser.GREATER) {
        return left > right;
    }
    else {
        return left < right;
    }

}

@Override
public Integer visitWhileLoop(WhileLoopContext ctx) {

    if(visit(ctx.getRuleContext())) {

    }

    return super.visitWhileLoop(ctx);
}
```

}

Most of the code in the visitor class i took from the book because i am just starting using ANTLR 4. I find it hard to believe that, aside from the grammar for the while loop, there is no mention of how to implement any visitors/listeners or actions for a simple While loop in the book written by Terence Parr. Can somebody help me with writing a Visitor/Listener Java code for a While loop?

Comment: Hi, this is more content from "Language Implementation Patterns": http://www.amazon.com/Language-Implementation-Patterns-Domain-Specific-Programming/dp/193435645X/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_y

Comment: @TheANTLRGuy I have that book and took a quick look at it to see if i could find how to implement a while loop and, sadly, it doesn't.

Comment: Have you looked at the pattern called tree-based interpreter? Page 230. it does not specifically do while loops I think, but it does Colin return which is much more complicated. It clearly shows how to move a virtual program counter through a tree.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I find it hard to believe that, aside from the grammar for the while loop, there is no mention of how to implement any visitors/listeners or actions for a simple While loop in the book written by Terence Parr.

That is because the ANTLR reference is about ANTLR, which is about parsing, not about the stage *after* parsing.

You can't do this:

> ```
> @Override
> public boolean visitGreaterEqual(GreaterEqualContext ctx) {
>     ...
> ```

You've already declared your visitor to return `Integer`s, so that's what every rule should return. Either make a custom wrapper `Value` that encapsulates your language's values (numbers, string, booleans), or just return `0` when a relation expression is false:

```
@Override
public Integer visitGreaterEqual(ExprParser.GreaterEqualContext ctx) {
    int left = this.visit(ctx.expr(0));
    int right = this.visit(ctx.expr(1));

    if (ctx.op.getType() == ExprParser.GREATER) {
        return left > right ? 1 : 0; // 0 is false (all other values are true)
    }
    else {
        return left < right ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Then you can write your `while` as follows:

```
@Override
public Integer visitWhile(ExprParser.WhileContext ctx) {

    // Evaluate the relational expression and continue the while
    // loop as long as it is true (does not equal zero).
    while (this.visit(ctx.relational()) != 0) {

        // Evaluate all statements inside the while loop.
        for (ExprParser.StatContext stat : ctx.stat()) {
            this.visit(stat);
        }
    }

    // 0 now also is false, so maybe return null instead which would be
    // some sort of VOID value (or make a proper Value class).
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the code above will fail when nesting `while` statements because the inner while would return `0` causing the outer while to stop looping. In such cases, you'd be better off creating a custom `Value` class and introduce some sort of `Value.VOID` instance that would not cause the loop to stop.

Running the following main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String expression = "n = 1\n" +
            "while (n < 10) {\n" +
            "  n\n" +
            "  n = n + 1\n" +
            "}\n";
    ExprLexer lexer = new ExprLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(expression));
    ExprParser parser = new ExprParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    new EvalVisitor().visit(parser.prog());
}
```

would print:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Also have a look at this demo language that uses ANTLR4 and `if` and `while` statements, as well as a custom `Value` object: https://github.com/bkiers/Mu

Comment: Thank you so very much Bart. Your solution works wonders! One question though - I am trying to wrap my head about what is being done in the visitor methods that makes all of this work. Take for example your implementation of the if statement: what you are doing is collecting all of the conditions + their blocks of code in a list. Then you check which of the conditions are true so that you can then visit the statement block corresponding to that specific condition - this is why you merged your condition + statement block, to easily locate the block that should be run. Am i correct?